# Images will not display when not in the wordpress upload folder

Tags: php, wordpress, image

Problem solved working between 2 servers, code on wrong server!!!
I'm fairly new to WordPress and have written a plugin to display jpeg images. The plugin works if I store & reference images in the upload folder but I want the images to be stored in a folder in the plugin folder I created. When I reference these images in the folder I created they will not display (no broken image just the alt name). I have checked folder permissions and they are 755, tried 777 but still nothing. This is the folder structure:

`/www/wp-content/plugins/guidancecards/cardimages`

`guidancecards` is where the php file is & `cardimages` is where the images are stored.

I'm currently outputting the images using:

```
echo "<img src=".$dir." alt=" .$image. " width='224' height='300' class='alignnone size-medium wp-image-13'"." /><br />";
```

Comment: Post your code (how you're calling the images).

Comment: echo "<img src=".$dir." alt=" .$image. " width='224' height='300' class='alignnone size-medium wp-image-13'"." /><br />";where $dir is $dir = PLUGIN_PATH.$image.".jpg"; and PLUGIN_PATH = define('PLUGIN_PATH',plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'cardimages/');